# Content-Security-Policy with Ionic and Socket.IO

Tags: android, cordova, socket.io, angular, ionic2

I need to use a socket.io connection in my ionic2 app.

I installed socket.io-client via npm so i can use it like this.

```
import * as io from 'socket.io-client'
...
...
this.socket = io(this.conf.connectionServer);
this.socket.on('connect', () =>{
...
...})
```

I does work when i'm using `ionic serve` in chrome or when running ionic `run -l`
but when i just `build` or `run` everything with ionic run it won't work.

i was able to log the error messsge on the screen of my android-device:

```
Error: Failed to execute: open: on :XMLHttpRequest:: Refused to connect to : http://file/socket.io/?EIO.....: because it violates the documents Content Security Policy.....
```

My Content Security Policy is:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" 
    content="default-src 'self';                                                                                                                                ;
        style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
        script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'
                    http://localhost:*
                    http://127.0.0.1:*

                    ;
        connect-src 'self'
                    ws://*
                    http://141.xx.xx.25:*
                    http://*.foobar.de
                    http://file/socket.io*
                    ;

        img-src *;
        media-src *
    ">
```

But i cant find the right solution.I

In Chrome the connection goes to: http://141.XX.XX.25/socket.io/
but on android it trys to connect to http://file/socket.io/

**Even if I set it to  `default-src *;` the Socket.io-Connection will only work when using `Serve` or `run with the Livereload-option`**

I'm using:

```
Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.1
Gulp local:
Ionic Version: 2.0.0-beta.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.17
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.8
OS:
Node Version: v5.6.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not realy related to CSP:
the cause is the setup of the socket.io connetion:

```
//this is wrong
this.statisticServer= "141.xx.xx.xx:8090/";
..
this.socket = io(this.conf.connectionServer);
```

But it should be:

```
//this is right
this.statisticServer= "http://141.xx.xx.xx:8090/";
...
this.socket = io(this.conf.connectionServer);
```

So there has to be an annoucement of **http** as protocol... may be a bug

As a CSP one can use:

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
                                default-src *;
                                style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; 
                                script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval';
                                connect-src * ;">
```

This CSP will allow almost everthing from everywhere.